# My textfields disappear when I put them in a linear lay-out in my XML-file

Tags: android, xml, android-linearlayout

I made an application in which a user can fill in some information in some fields. This works. But when I want to change the lay-out, I have a problem.
I want to have the fields that the user should fill in, in a colored block (background3). So, I put the code in my XML-file in a linear lay-out, but when I do this, all the fields that the user should fill in dissappear. Does anyone know what I did wrong or how I can correct this?

This is the code of my XML-file:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <LinearLayout 
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
     android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01" 
     android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     android:background="@drawable/background"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:padding="30dip">



        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
           >
                     <include layout="@layout/header"/>
         </LinearLayout>

         <LinearLayout
              xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="0dp"
             android:layout_weight="6"
             android:background="@color/background3"
             android:orientation="vertical" >   
            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/button1_label" 
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:text="Voer hieronder je rooster in:" 
                android:textSize="24.5sp" 
                android:layout_gravity="center" 
                android:layout_marginBottom="25dip" />

            <TextView 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:text="Dag:" 
                android:layout_gravity="center" 
                android:textSize="14.5sp" />

           <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/dag_spinner"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:text="Uur:" 
                android:layout_gravity="center" 
                android:textSize="14.5sp" />

            <EditText 
                android:id="@+id/uur" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:text="Vak:" 
                android:layout_gravity="center" 
                android:textSize="14.5sp" />

            <EditText 
                android:id="@+id/vak" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:text="Docent:" 
                android:layout_gravity="center" 
                android:textSize="14.5sp" />

            <EditText 
                android:id="@+id/docent" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


            <TextView 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:text="Lokaal:" 
                android:layout_gravity="center" 
                android:textSize="14.5sp" />

            <EditText 
                android:id="@+id/lokaal" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <LinearLayout 
                android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02" 
                android:orientation="horizontal" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:paddingLeft="20sp">

                    <Button 
                        android:text="Gegevens opslaan" 
                        android:id="@+id/Button01add" 
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                        android:layout_marginTop="20sp" 
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20sp">  
                    </Button>

                    <Button 
                        android:text="Terug" 
                        android:id="@+id/Button01home" 
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                        android:layout_marginTop="20sp" 
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20sp">      
                    </Button>

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
   </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your layout's height is `0dp`, use `wrap_content` instead. So change to this:

```
<LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_weight="6"
         android:background="@color/background3"
         android:orientation="vertical" >
```

And you don't have to declare the android namespace in every layout (the `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` line)

And in your

```
<TextView 
            android:id="@+id/button1_label" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:text="Voer hieronder je rooster in:" 
            android:textSize="24.5sp" 
            android:layout_gravity="center" 
            android:layout_marginBottom="25dip" />
```

there is a 25dp bottom margin, try to reduce that.

**EDIT:**
AND your `layout_height` is set to `fill_parent`, set it to `wrap_content`

Comment: I changed it, and now only the titel 'Voer hieronder je rooster in' is shown. The rest still misses...

Comment: Can you upload a screenshot of what you see?